# How to enable Magento 1.9.x cache to store in database

Tags: magento-1.9, database, cache

I was searching on how to enable cache to store in database but found nothing. So, my question is:
Does magento do really has the feature to stores cache in the database?

I found out these tables - `core_cache` and `core_cache_tag` in the database. Does it meant to store Magento cache? I found that the tables is always empty even I enable cache from Magento admin panel.

Comment: This might be what you are looking for, using the DB as cache https://www.sonassi.com/blog/magento-kb/controlling-the-cache-size-when-using-database-as-a-backend-magento

Comment: thx @mbalparda..so it possible to save cache in db. now i just to know the way how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edit the `app/etc/local.xml` and add this inside the `<global>` tag (position not important)

```
<cache>
    <backend>database</backend>
</cache>
```

Comment: great...ill try this first and see if it works or not..thx @Marius

Comment: Whilst this is possible, it should NEVER be used. Use Redis.

Comment: ok..i just try this...i looked into the cache table in database. it is worked. BUT...my store page turn got this SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away

Comment: Ben Lessani, I was thinking about that also. yet to implement that later. Just want to do some testing and compare with this database way of caching

Comment: Oh yeah...I forgot about this. I agree with @BenLessani-Sonassi. You should never use that. It kind of defeats the purpose of cache.

Comment: btw, can redis cache layouts and blocks of the magento? like magento cache system.

Comment: You should use Varnish for that @fiq

Comment: alrite..thx to all of you guyz.. :)

Comment: `can redis cache layouts and blocks` - That's the whole point of Redis. It is a cache store for the standard Magento caches. It drops in place to replace the default file based caching mechanism.